# Error in rep(value, length.out = n) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Tags: r

To replace 10 to 15 columns in my data. getting above error.

```
     cols_name <- c(10:15)
     library(plyr)
     for (i in 1:ncol(dfchurn[,cols_name])) {
     dfchurn[,cols_name][,i] <- as.factor
     (plyr::mapvalues(dfchurn[,cols_name][,i],
     from=c("No internet service"),to=c("No")))
     }
```

Comment: Sorry . It is to replace few rows in those colunms with name No internet service to No.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Do you need `dfchurn[cols_name][dfchurn[cols_name] == "No internet service"] <- 'No'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is all you need?

```r
## First some random data
set.seed( 100 )
cols_name <- c(10:15)
dfchurn <- as.data.frame(
    matrix(
        sample( c(LETTERS[1:6], "No internet service"), size=10*20, replace=TRUE ),
        ncol=20
    )
)

## 'No' inserted:
dfchurn[,cols_name] %>% apply( 2, mapvalues, from="No internet service", to="No" )
```

Comment: just use the solution ronak gave u it's more efficient

Comment: That's a rather onesided focus